# Forwarding of return values. Is std::forward is needed?

Tags: c++, c++11, return, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I am writing library which wraps a lot of functions and methods from other library.  To avoid coping of return values I am applying `std::forward` like so:

```
template<class T>
T&& wrapper(T&& t) { 
   f(t);  // t passed as lvalue  
   return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

`f` returns `void` and takes `T&&` (or overloaded on valueness). Wrapper  always returns wrappers's param and on returned value should preserve valuness of argument. Do I actually need to use `std::forward` in `return`? Does RVO makes it superfluous? Does the fact that it is a reference (R or L) makes it superfluous? Is it needed if return is not last function statement (inside some if)?

It is debatable if `wrapper()` should return `void` or `T&&`, because caller have access to evaluated value via arg (which is reference, R or L). But in my case I need to return value so that `wrapper()` can be used in expressions.

It might be irrelevant to the question, but it is known that functions `f` does not steal from `t`, so 1st use of `std::forward` in `f(std::forward<T>(t))` is superfluous and it was removed by me.

I've wrote small test: https://gist.github.com/3910503

Test shows, that returning unforwarded `T`- does creates extra copy in gcc48 and clang32 with -O3 (RVO does not kicks in).

Also, I was not able to get bad behavior from UB in:

```
auto&& tmp = wrapper(42);
```

It does not prove anything of cause because it is *undefined* behavior (if it is UB).

Comment: You worry about copying of return values but if there's a chance `f` steals away its parameter then what's the point of the return value at all?

Comment: It is known that `f` won't steal it parameter. I agree that it is debatable why to return from `wrapper`, if return value is known (argument is reference). But I need to return, so that `wrapper` can be used in function-style expressions.

Comment: @LucDanton - after answering to you (and saying that `f` won't steal its parameters), I've realized that I probably do not need forward in `f(std::forward<T>(t))`

Comment: Well in an ideal world `f` would take `T const&` I suppose, in which case you wouldn't forward indeed. However I've found myself writing such function templates that take `T&&` even though they won't modify their parameters ever, for various reasons.

Comment: I swear, if I see someone call a `&&` a "universal reference" again...

Comment: @NicolBolas - you don't like the term, or I am using it incorrectly?  I know of cause that `T&&` are not always universal references.

Comment: What is a "universal reference"?

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: The term "universal reference" is not proper C++ terminology; you will not find it in the C++ specification. At present, the only place I've heard it from is a presentation by Scott Meyers. And I really hope it doesn't catch on.

Comment: @GManNickG -  http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11

Comment: @Nicol : Stephan T Lavavej from MS uses the term a lot as well, and given his plethora of Channel9 videos, the term is catching on, like it or not.

Comment: @NicolBolas Still a better named idiom than RAII. Also, I heard "forwarding reference" is coming to replace it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the case that you do know that `t` will not be in a moved-from state after the call to `f`, your two somewhat sensible options are:

- return `std::forward<T>(t)` with type `T&&`, which avoids any construction but allows for writing e.g. `auto&& ref = wrapper(42);`, which leaves `ref` a dangling reference
- return `std::forward<T>(t)` with type `T`, which at worst requests a move construction when the parameter is an rvalue -- this avoids the above problem for prvalues but potentially steals from xvalues

In all cases you need `std::forward`. Copy elision is not considered because `t` is always a reference.

Comment: Would `auto&& ref = wrapper(42)` leave a dangling reference? I thought the lifetime of the temporary would be extended to the scope of `ref` (see first comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272705/how-can-i-create-a-macro-which-uses-a-value-multiple-times-without-copying-it )

Comment: @Claudiu The comment you mention first exhibits an example of a *non*-extended temporary, i.e. in `auto&& tmp = id(5);`. Here the temporary created from `5` only lives until the semicolon. This is the dangerous, non-obvious behaviour I’m warning about.

Comment: @Claudiu The lifetime of a temporary is only extended if a temporary was bound by a reference  (a.k.a when returning by value). If a function returns any kind of reference, even a r-value reference, it's not a temporary.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what this function gets passed, it results in undefined behavior! More precisely, if you pass a non-lvalue, *i.e.* an rvalue, to this function, the value referenced by the returned reference will be stale.

Also `T&&` isn't a "universal reference" although the effect is somewhat like a universal reference in that `T` can be deduced as `T&`  or `T const&`. The problematic case is when it gets deduced as `T`: the arguments get passed in as temporary and die after the function returns but before anything can get hold of a reference to it.

The use of `std::forward<T>(x)` is limited to, well, forwarding objects when calling another function: what came in as a temporary looks like an lvalue within the function. Using `std::forward<T>(x)` lets `x` look like a temporary if it came in as one - and, thus, allow moving from `x` when creating the argument of the called function.

When you return an object from a function there are a few scenarios you might want to take care of but none of them involves `std::forward()`:

- If the type is actually a reference, either `const` or non-`const`, you don't want to do anything with the object and just return the reference.
- If all `return` statements use the same variable or all are using a temporary, copy/move elision can be used and will be used on decent compilers. Since the copy/move elision is an optimization, it doesn't necessarily happen, however.
- If always the same local variable or a temporary is returned it can be moved from if there is a move constructor, otherwise the object will be copied.
- When different variables are returned or when the return involves an expression, references may still be returned but copy/move elision will not work, nor will it be directly possible to move from the result if isn't a temporary. In these cases you need to use `std::move()` to allow moving from the local object.

In most of these cases the produced type is `T` and you should return `T` rather than `T&&`. If `T` is an lvalue type the result may not be an lvalue type, though, and it may be necessary to remove the reference qualification from the return type. In the scenario you specifically asked about the type `T` works.

Comment: Prvalues may be problematic and can indeed result in stale references, but xvalues aren't as likely to end up with UB -- not that I find returning a moved-from value particularly useful.

Comment: "if you pass an rvalue to this function, the value referenced by the returned reference will be stale". I'm probably being dense, but why is that then? If the caller passed in an rvalue to a temporary, doesn't that temporary live at least until the end of the caller's full-expression, hence long enough to be referenced by the return value of this function? Hence something like `my_Foo_vector.emplace_back(wrapper(Foo());`. I see that returning `T` would also allow that, I just don't see when returning `T&&` yields a stale reference.

Comment: The temporary you create, conceptually, isn't the object the function sees! The function sees, conceptually, a copy of this object. The life-time of the parameter ends earlier than the full expression in which temporary is created. In particular, 5.2.2 [expr.call], paragraph 4 contains the following sentence: "... The lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns. .." In practice you will see the copy/move of this object being elided. Even if I got this logic wrong, the object is stale in the sense that it is being moved from, conceptually, when being passed on.

Comment: Actually, I think I have confused myself: the rvalue reference is still a reference, i.e., there shouldn't be any copy of the temporary and it lives long enough to return a reference to it. That said, there is still a problem but it is even deeper than I thought: in the call `f(std::forward<T>(t))` the function `f()` get permission to move the object from `t` and referencing `t` inside `wrapper()` needs to assume that `t` is moved from. If `f()` doesn't move from the passed object, there is no need to use `std::forward<T>()` when calling `f()`.

Comment: OK, slowly coming around: the call to `f()` shouldn't `std::forward<T>(t)` to the called function if the content of `t` can't be stolen: The purpose of forwarding to make it possible to have the content stolen. On the other hand, when returning `t` as a `T&&` it is necessary to restore rvalueness for `t`, i.e., to feed a return type of `T&&` using `std::forward<T>(t)` is what get's the return right. That said, I think the interface is still too fragile.

Comment: +1, thanks for your very detailed answer.   I my particular case wrapper  always returns wrappers's param and on return value should preserve valuness of argument.

Answer (score 3):

No you dont need to use `std::forward` better dont return r-value reference at all because it can prevent of NRVO optimization. You can read more about move semantics in this article: [Article](http://pizer.wordpress.com/2009/04/13/c0x-do-people-understand-rvalue-references/)

Comment: (N)RVO cannot apply to function arguments, only to locals with automatic storage duration.