# Perfect forwarding of return values, undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, return, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I have a set of functions where I employ template specialisation to perform transforms on certain values. However, for many types I want to pass the values through unchanged.

To pass a value unchanged I have something like the following function as the default:

```
template< typename arg >
arg&& convert( arg&& x )
{
    return std::forward<arg>( x );
}
```

This seems great but according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948078/forwarding-of-return-values-is-stdforward-is-needed) it runs the risk of leaving a dangling reference in a statement like:

```
int&& x = convert( 5 );
```

If I only use this inline in function arguments, is this risk avoided?

For example, do I run into undefined behaviour if I do something like...

```
void foo( int&& x )
{
    // Do something with x...
}

foo( convert( 5 ) );
```

Comment: Some context... like why can't you just pass `5` or use `std::move()`

Comment: Say I wanted to write a wrapper for functions that did nothing to most types, but added one to all integers for some reason (this isn't my use case, but let's say it is), then I could use convert for all arguments regardless of type (e.g., in something like a variadic function), and write an integer specialisation for the convert( x ) template that adds one to each integer.

Comment: Your forwarding code is wrong, it should be `std::forward<arg>(x);`.

Comment: So it was, thank you.

Comment: If you use it as function argument, it's fine. Temporaries are destroyed after the full expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

> For example, do I run into undefined behaviour if I do something like...

No. The rule, from [[class.temporary]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.9), emphasis mine, is:

> A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call persists until the **completion of the *full-expression* containing the call**.

Our temporary (`5`) is bound to a reference parameter in a function call (to `arg&&` in `convert()`), so it persists until the end of the full-expression (which is the all of `foo(convert(5))` ). So this is fine, as long as you don't let a reference to `x` escape `foo()`.